# How do I use Linq to query nested dynamic BsonDocuments?

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

```
public class Foo
{
  public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
  public BsonDocument properties { get; set; }
}

public void FindFoos()
{
  var client = new MongoClient(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MongoDB"].ConnectionString);
  var server = client.GetServer();
  var db = server.GetDatabase("FooBar");
  //var collection = db.GetCollection<GeoJsonFeature<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates>>("Sections");
  var collection = db.GetCollection<Foo>("Foos");



  collection.Insert(new Foo
  {
    properties = new BsonDocument{
                     {"Foo" , "foo1"},
                     {"Bar" , "bar1"}
                   }
  });
  collection.Insert(new Foo
  {
    properties = new BsonDocument{
                     {"Foo" , "foo2"},
                     {"Bar" , "bar2"}
                   }
  });


  var query = Query<Foo>.Where(foo => foo.properties.AsQueryable().Any(property => property.Name == "Foo" && property.Value.AsString == "foo1"));

  var result = collection.Find(query).First();
}
```

calling FindFoos results in the following exception:

Unsupported where clause: Queryable.Any(Queryable.AsQueryable(foo.properties), (BsonElement property) => ((property.Name == "Foo") && (property.Value.AsString == "foo1"))).

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web     request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unsupported where clause: Queryable.Any(Queryable.AsQueryable(foo.properties), (BsonElement property) => ((property.Name == "Foo") && (property.Value.AsString == "foo1"))).

at the line:

```
var query = Query<Foo>.Where(foo => foo.properties.AsQueryable().Any(property => property.Name == "Foo" && property.Value.AsString == "foo1"));
```

I can do this query easily in the mongodb shell as:

```
db.Foos.find( {'properties.Foo' : 'foo1'} );
```

What is the correct way to do this query with Linq?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm having similar issues.. I have a nested complex BsonDocument, and I need to get all the BsonElements that are of a certain "type". Couldn't find a solution.

Comment: I believe I just ended up not using Linq to generate the mongodb query.  Not sure if this has changed with the latest version of the mongodb c# driver, but I believe I confirmed that, at the time, it was not possible to query mongodb sub-documents with Linq (as the error messsages say, it's an unsupported where clause as far as the driver is concerned).

Answer (score 0):

Try LINQ's `SelectMany()` method.  It is used to flatten nested collections.  Instead of using nested for loops, we can do the task in a more 'LINQ' way.

Ex given below -

```
Master m1 = new Master() { name = "A", lstObj = new List<obj> { new obj { i = 1, s = "C++" }, new obj { i = 1, s = "C#" }, new obj { i = 1, s = "Java" } } };

Master m2 = new Master() { name = "A", lstObj = new List<obj> { new obj { i = 4, s = "PHP" }, new obj { i = 5, s = "Ruby" }, new obj { i = 6, s = "Perl" } } };

List<Master> lstMasters = new List<Master> { m1, m2 };
var result = lstMasters.SelectMany(m => m.lstObj).Where(o => o.s == "PHP");
```

Just replace the `Master` class with your `BsonDocument`.