# C# Perform query inside a BsonDocument to find equivalent documents

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, bson

I have a complex nested dynamic BsonDocument and I need to query that document to find all the "records" that have the same "type".

An example of a Json is :

```
{
"Id": "",
"CategoryId": "41",
"FormVersion": "4",
"Metadata":{
    "title": "some title",
    "author": "Kevin B.",
    "location": {
        "url": "ed5cf2ea-c920-43b2-807b-65f5e4cac650.jpeg",
      "type": "upload",
        "size": "1001",
        "format": "application/json",
        "numbers": [1,2,3,4]
    },
    "file": {
        "url": "ed5cf2ea-c920-43b2-807b-65f5e4cacddf50.jpeg",
      "type": "upload",
        "size": "1001",
        "format": "application/json",
        "numbers": [1,2,3,4]
    }
}
}
```

This is mapped with a custom ModelBinder in my controller to this class:

**Content**

```
public class Content : Base
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int FormVersion { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public BsonDocument Metadata { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see above, the "Metadata" get's mapped into a BsonDocument.

Now, Before save the whole document in MongoDB, I need to find all the "records" that has the type "upload". I need this because I need to move the files that are in a temp folder and this records have the temp file URI.

In the example, **location** and **file** are objects that has the type "upload". I need somehow to query this bsondocument and get only these documents, move the files and save.

I tried work with linq but no success. I've looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290133/how-do-i-use-linq-to-query-nested-dynamic-bsondocuments) but I don't have a collection to work with. It's only an object.

Answer (score 0):

When you use LINQ, essentially you construct an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, there `T` is your document type. LINQ is then parsing this expression and uses property accessors to build the database-specific query.

You are trying to use a dynamic object property content as filter. This will not work since LINQ has no idea how properties are named inside the content of your dynamic object.

The only way to query such schema is to use native MongoDb queries since there you can just compose a query using normal strings.